# How could I quickly look-up items in a List of loaded entities

Tags: performance, entity-framework, c#-4.0, collections

I have built an MVC 5 application, using EF 6 to query the database. One page show a cross table of two dimensions: substances against properties of these substances. It is rendered as an html table.Many cells do not have a value. This is what it looks like:

```
        sub 1  sub 2  sub 3
prop A   1.0
prop B          1.5     X
prop C   0.6            Y
```

The cell values are actually more complex, including tool tips, footnotes, etc.

I implemented the generation of the html table, by the following steps:

1. create a list of unique properties;
2. create a list of unique substances;
3. loop through the properties;
4. render a row for each;
5. loop through the substances;
6. See if there is a value for the combination of property and substances;
7. render the cell's value or an empty one.

Using the ANTS performance profiler, I found out that step 6 has a huge performance issue with increasing numbers of substances and properties, the hit count exploding to hundreds of millions, with a few hundred substances and a few tens of properties (the largest selection the user can make). The execution time is many minutes. It seems to scale N(substances)^2 * N(properties)^2.

The code looks like:

```
Value currentValue = 
values.Where(val => val.substance.Id == currentSubstanceId 
&& val.property.Id == currentPropertyId).SingleOrDefault();
```

where values is a List and Value is an entity, which I read from to render the cells. values had been pre-loaded from the database and no queries are shown by the SQL Server Profiler.

Since not all cells have a value, I thought it best to loop through the row and columns and see if there is a value. I cannot just loop through the list of values.

What could I try to improve this? I thought about:

1. Create some sort of C# object, using the substance.Id and property.Id as a compound key and fill it from the List object. Which would be fastest?
2. Create some Linq query which returns an object which already contains the empty cells, like (substance cross join properties) left join values. I could do this in SQL easily, but could this be done with Linq? Could the object which stores the result have the Value as a member field, so I can still use it to render the cells?
3. Stop pre-loading and just run a database query for the value of each combination, possibly benefiting from database indexes.
4. I am considering restricting the number of substances and properties the user may select, but I would rather not do that.

**Addtional info**

As requested by C.Zonnenberg, some more info about the query.

The query to fill the list of values is basically as follows:
I create an `IQueryable` to which I add filters for requested substances and properties. I then include the substances, property and value details, found in related entities. I then execute `query.ToList()`. The actual SQL query, as seen by the SQL Profiler looks complex, involving SubstanceId IN () and PropertyId IN (), but it takes far less then a second to execute.

It returns a list of proxies, like: {System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.SubstancePropertyValue_078F758A4FF9831024D2690C4B546F07240FAC82A1E9D95D3826A834DCD91D1E}

Comment: How do you fill your 'values' variable? Can you add that to your question?

Comment: One modification has eased the pain a bit: I now use the following selection: `Value currentValue = 
values.Where(val => val.substanceId == currentSubstanceId 
&& val.propertyId == currentPropertyId).SingleOrDefault();`, in which the foreign keys in the base entity are used, rather then the primairy keys of the included entities. This increases the speed about a factor ten, but not the huge number of calls.

Comment: Do the `values` include the `property` and `substance` objects? It would be very slow if they were fetched by lazy loading.

Comment: @GertArnold, they are included in the values, but explicitly included in the query as well, so they are loaded all at once, as I have verified using the SQL Profiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your best bet is your first option. But to do that efficiently I would also modify the source data (`values`) and turn it into a dictionary, so you have a structure that's optimized for indexed lookup:

```
var dict = values.ToDictionary(e => 
                       Tuple.Create(e.substance.id, e.propertyid),
                       e => e.Value);
```

Then for each cell:

```
Value currentValue ;
dict.TryGetValue(Tuple.Create(currentSubstanceId, currentPropertyId), 
                 out currentValue );
```

Further, you may benefit from parallelization by fetching the cell values in a [`Parallel.ForEach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) looping through all substances, for instance.

Comment: This solution has worked very well. The CPU time needed for the biggest possible selection has dropped from many minutes to a about 20 ms!

Comment: For anyone interested, I used `var dict = values.ToDictionary(e => ... , e => e);`, in order to have the complete object availabe at lookups.

Comment: thanks for suggesting Parallel.ForEach. However, I am reluctant to start using the parallel class, because performance is fine for now, and I am not sure what pitfalls I need to understand and I wonder if it would increase speed if many users are sending requests to my web server.